# Disk Trace (32 bit): what is it?

Tags: windows-8.1

What is `Disk Trace (32 bits)`?

Sometimes, usually when I don't have any open application, it uses up to 30% of my CPU for a minute or so.

I use Windows 8.1, 64 bits.

Comment: run ProcessExplorer/Taskmgr and look for the commandline. From where is the tool started?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it's part of this package:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-trace-analyzer

It is included in the Intel driver updater, if you agree to it's sending of feedback. It probably analyses the performance of the tool on your computer and uploads the results to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

DiskTrace.exe is part of DiskTrace and developed by Intel Corporation according to the DiskTrace.exe version information.

DiskTrace.exe's description is "DiskTrace"
DiskTrace.exe is digitally signed by Intel(R) Software Development Products.
DiskTrace.exe is usually located in the 'C:\Program Files\Intel\SUR\WILLAMETTE\ESRV\' folder.
None of the anti-virus scanners at VirusTotal reports anything malicious about DiskTrace.exe.

Vendor and version information [?]

Product name DiskTrace 
Company name Intel Corporation 
File description DiskTrace 
Internal name DiskTrace.exe 
Original filename DiskTrace.exe 
Legal copyright Copyright © Intel 2013 
Product version 1.0.3.0 
File version 1.0.3.0

The following is the available information on DiskTrace.exe:

Product name DiskTrace 
Company name Intel Corporation 
File description DiskTrace 
Internal name DiskTrace.exe 
Original filename DiskTrace.exe 
Legal copyright Copyright © Intel 2013 
Product version 1.0.3.0 
File version 1.0.3.0

Digital signatures [?]

This file has a valid digital signature.

Signer name Intel(R) Software Development Products 
Certificate issuer name Intel External Basic Issuing CA 3B 
Certificate serial number 330000b65a6f1172f84a8aef7100020000b65a

VirusTotal report

None of the 56 anti-virus programs at VirusTotal detected the DiskTrace.exe file.

None of the 56 anti-virus programs detected the DiskTrace.exe file.

Hashes [?]

MD5 18bf626cf867e5eff84cbc3a295c4989 
SHA256 e1a37c9c6a0662b5e87bbcd823df8e82f5b8e174b5a5f117e434c5f02410c8a5

Error Messages

These are some of the error messages that can appear related to disktrace.exe:

disktrace.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience.

disktrace.exe - Application Error. The instruction at "0xXXXXXXXX" referenced memory at "0xXXXXXXXX". The memory could not be "read/written". Click on OK to terminate the program.

DiskTrace has stopped working.

End Program - disktrace.exe. This program is not responding.

disktrace.exe is not a valid Win32 application.

disktrace.exe - Application Error. The application failed to initialize properly (0xXXXXXXXX). Click OK to terminate the application.

For further info take assistance from http://www.freefixer.com/library/file/DiskTrace.exe-200302/

Comment: This could be an answer but it has severe formatting issues. Also a link back to vendor site would be more convincing rather than some random freefixer.com